# Like with an apostrophe in the seach

Tags: oracle

How do I search for "Land's End" in a LIKE syntax?

```
OR UPPER(MOPACTIVITY.MOPDESCRIPTION) LIKE '%LANDS'END%'
```

The apostrophe is making the code fail, but it is part of the company name.  How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

double it! or use special quoting http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=311